# Using the Search Paging Web Part

Tags: search, web-part

This is my first time working with the search components of SharePoint in much detail so any advice would be helpful here.

I have a custom search results page created to match our corporate intranet (not sharepoint.)

The search query is passed in using the the query string parameter so this page is essentially an exact replica of the intranet in static html but with the required elements to render as an ASP.Net page as well as the SPWebPartManager and a single WebPartZone containing the Search Core Results web part.

This works brilliantly!  But you cannot see how many results you got returned or page through them.

So I need the Search Paging and Search Statistics web parts.  Now both of these require connecting to the Search Core Results web part (according to MS documentation), however when I try to add a web part connection in SharePoint designer I get an error dialog saying:

*The Search Paging Web Part does not support connections.*

So how can I connect these up?  I cannot use the browser UI as this is a custom page created in SharePoint Designer.

Help is appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3):

The Search Web Parts does not use Web Part Connections. Instead they use an object on the page called `SearchResultHiddenObject`.

When you add these Web Parts set the `QueryID` property of the Web Parts (statistics, paging etc) to `QueryId.Query1` ("Cross-Web Part query ID" in the UI).

Comment: Thanks but this did not fix the issue.  Good point though so +1